# Realm - accessing field names without hardcoding while query building

Tags: android, realm

I'm querying Realm using the snippet below where I'm providing hardcoded `fieldName` which I believe is quite error-prone. I've checked realm documentation (to no avail) but in the official example (https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/newsreaderExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/newsreader/model/entity/NYTimesStory.java), they're using static fields to access from queries. Which, again, I think is quite "dangerous" considering future field name changes and etc. So, what I wonder is whether there is a solution that I'm missing out?

Real example:

```
 override fun getSection(section: Section): RealmResults<Article> {
         return realm.where(Article::class.java)
         .equalTo("section", 
         ,section.section).findAllAsync()
 }
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
 override fun getSection(section: Section): RealmResults<Article> {
        return realm.where(Article::class.java)
        .equalTo(Article.SECTION,  // or ArticleX.SECTION, X being name extension
        ,section.section).findAllAsync()
 }
```

Comment: You can look at `RealmFieldNamesHelper` IIRC. Unfortunately it's not updated to be incremental annotation processor though, but it helps.

Comment: I don't think build time would take minutes to build which is worth to build type-safe queries. Unfortunately, it's kinda side project and seems on hold. Apparently, hardcoding is the way to go for now. What I wonder the most is why would such a library undermine the importance of type-safety by not introducing an out-of-the-box solution?

Comment: Just generally an API design decision mistake, if you ask me. Both the Criteria Builder API (which is bad, but at least it has metamodels) and QueryDSL could handle the ability to create type-safe paths by which a query can be built, so it is clearly not impossible. If you don't like the auto-gen, I used to create `enum Fields {` inside the RealmObject for the same purpose.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I was searching something unrelated and got here. `enum Fields {` is still super unsafe. Imagine you delete some field and forgot updating your enum class.

Comment: yes, that's why you can use RealmFieldNamesHelper because it's autogenerated